# How to add a label to xbl component Orbeon

Tags: label, orbeon, toolbox, xbl

I want to add an input field called name, so I created an XBL component and i add it in the directory `ressources/xbl` in Orbeon. I want to create the label "name" but it didn't work.

```
<xbl:xbl xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
     xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
     xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
     xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl">

<xbl:binding element="fr|tutorial-input" id="fr-tutorial-input" xxbl:mode="lhha binding value">
    <xbl:template>
        <!-- Input points to the external single-node binding -->
        <xf:input ref="xxf:binding('fr-tutorial-input')"/>
    </xbl:template>
</xbl:binding>
<fr:tutorial-input>
  <xf:label>name</xf:label>
```

Comment: So I am not sure what you are trying to do: to have the component always have the label "name"? Here you put your `<fr:tutorial-input>` element within the definition of your `<fr:tutorial-input>` component, is that right?

Comment: @ebruchez - Could you please answer above question. I have requirement like http://stackoverflow.com/q/39327963/2478134